# How can I save files inside a temporary folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am obtaining the directory of the `temp` or `tmp` folder, and creating a folder called "TemporaryImages" from it, which as the name says, I am only going to use it to save images with low resolution temporarily.

The problem is that "TemporaryImages" is being created successfully, but the images are not being saved within it, and I don't understand where I'm screwing up.

I'm using C# ASP.NET, on  a Linux server.

This code receives a list of images fetched from a database. With "TemporalFolder()" I create or get the directory of the temporary folder, and with the function "SaveImage()" I am sending it the name of the image, the directory of the folder, and the new size of the image.

```
private void ChangeImageSize(List<OrderViewModel> orderViewModels)
        {
            const int thumbnailWidth = 500;
            string tempFolder;

            try
            {
                tempFolder = TemporaryFolder();

                foreach (var item in orderViewModels)
                {
                    var imageResult = Image.Load("wwwroot/" + item.getImages());

                    this.SaveImage(imageResult, tempFolder, thumbnailWidth);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.error = ex.Message.ToString();
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

With this function I seek to save the image inside the temporary folder:

```
  private void SaveImage(Image image, string name, int resizeWidth)
{
    var width = image.Width;
    var height = image.Height;

    if (width > resizeWidth)
    {
        height = (int)((double)resizeWidth / width * height);
        width = resizeWidth;
    }

    picture
        .Mutate(i => i.Resize(new Size(width, height)));

    image.Metadata.ExifProfile = null;

    image.SaveAsJpeg(name, new JpegEncoder
    {
        Quality = 100
    });
}
```

This is the function to create and get the temporary folder:

```
private string TemporaryFolder()
{
    DirectoryInfo result = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetTempPath() + "TemporaryImages/");

    return result.FullName;
}
```

Comment: If you are running on a IS server your can't write to file system.  You can use a Network Drive for temporary storage.

Comment: It works with a shared Virtual folder? I mean, create a shared virtual folder, and access to it when needed?

Comment: A virtual folder is inside the application and not on the machine.  When deploying on a server you usually do not have access to the file system so than hackers cannot attach the machine.  Best choice is to use a folder on a Network Drive.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you are not specifying any file name when saving the file. There are a few options on what filenames to use:

1. Use numbers, check current files to avoid duplicates.
2. Use Guids, they are guaranteed to be unique
3. Use [Path.GetTempFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettempfilename?view=net-6.0), this will give a full filename in the root of the temp folder.

Secondly, if you are running asp.net you likely do not have write-permission to the temp folder. You probably do not want to grant your web-process access to your systems temp-folder since that might have security implications.

If the files are truly *temporary*, as in only valid during a single request, I would recommend keeping them in memory. Images can be saved to a memory stream just fine, and this avoids any issue with cleanup etc. The main reason to write such temporary data to files is either memory constraints, and this should be fairly rare today, or some API that require actual files.

If you are rather want a short lived image storage I would suggest following the standard practices for storing images, i.e. use a database to keep a list of images, a configurable storage folder with correct permissions to store images, and some cleanup process to periodically remove unneeded images, etc.

Comment: So, what is recommended is to save the files (in my case, images) in the memory, and delete them when I don't need them?

Comment: @Popo, I would recommend keeping images in memory if you can, that way you can just drop the reference to free the image, and restarting the server automatically removes all images. But it really depend on how the images are used, how long they are needed etc.

Comment: they will be displayed in a gallery dynamically, and when the user changes view, they will be deleted. What I want is to copy the original images in a Temporary folder and lower their resolution so they weigh less and the web page does not take long to load (since many images will be displayed), show the copied images with lower quality in the gallery and if someone if you want to download an image, download the original with maximum quality

Comment: @popo Then you probably should store the images in both high and low resolution. At least if you want scalability, since reading and downsampling high res images will be fairly resource intensive. But if you want to downscale on demand, there is little reason to save to disk in between, just downsample low res image in memory and send to the client directly.

Comment: Okey, I will try to save them in memory temporally without using `Bitmap`